# BroadCastReceiver working if app got Forced Stopped

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have BroadCastReceiver **BCR** registered for action string **S** in app **App#1**
From app **App#2** I broadCast intent with correct action string (**S**)

If app **App#2** was already opened.. intent is received meaning `onReceive()` from **BCR** is called

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     System.err.println("### ### MyBroadcastReceiver ### onReceive()");
```

If **App#2** was Forced Closed (from Setting-Applications) or never oppened (fresh restarted device)
same broadcast with same action string (**S**) does not reach my broadCastReceiver  **BCR**

Code for broadcasting intent (note no flags.. didnt know if its needed.. & that string is **S**)

```
String action = "customActionString.something"; 
Intent intent = new Intent(action);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

What am I missing? Is this a Tag problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If App#2 was Forced Closed (from Setting-Applications) or never oppened (fresh restarted device) same broadcast with same action string (S) does not reach my broadCastReceiver BCR

Correct.

> What am I missing?

An activity, perhaps.

Quoting [Dianne Hackborn](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18225):

> Starting with [Android] 3.1 when applications are installed they are in a “stopped” state so they will not be able to run until the user explicitly launches them. Pressing Force Stop will return them to this state.

This was described somewhat poorly in [the Android 3.1 release notes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols).

Answer (score 0):

So adding: FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES will make intent reach the broadcastReceivers from apps in "stopped" state

& you (@CommonsWare) are right, i was better in using a Activity, since intention was to open a activity, but now i use this code, it works well in all cases (app opened & in background - it will bring it to front (with whatever activity was previously open), app in closed state - it will open it (from main activity), no app installed - Toast warning)

```
try {
      Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
"otherAppPackage");
      m_ContainerActivity.startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("SomeTag", "otherAppPackage app not found");
      Toast.makeText(m_ContainerActivity, "<app name> is not installed on device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```